# Should ensureIndex be called in application setup?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

Is it appropriate to call `ensureIndex` whenever application changes, e.g. in `app.configure`?

Does it have any downsides besides slightly slower startup time compared to setting it only for new mongo instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ensure index is called on an already existing index it will register as a no op. This means it should not slow down your App at all if called from `app.configure`.

I cannot see any other downsides due to the fact that the function will just run and not create the index if it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

I typically call `ensureIndex()` from application init, wrapped in a check for an expected existing collection. If the collection already exists, assume the DB is already properly indexed and skip the `ensureIndex()` calls.

More here:
[Mongodb: when to call ensureIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000777/mongodb-when-to-call-ensureindex/#19390845)