# Is the advantage of calling ensureindex in mongodb just speed?

Tags: mongodb

I've been reading about ensureindex ([Mongodb: when to call ensureIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000777/mongodb-when-to-call-ensureindex)) , ([Pymongo / MongoDB: create index or ensure index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912661/pymongo-mongodb-create-index-or-ensure-index)) and mongodb documentation, but i havent come to a conclusion about the use of ensureindex.
Doesnt mongodb create an Id for every document? Why do i need another index?
In case I have a document like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Jon Secada",
    "Date of Birth": "09-19-1983",
    "Address": "1 chemin des Loges",
    "City": "VERSAILLES"
}
```

Whats the advantage of calling ensureindex on "name" for example?

Comment: Efficient searches by `name`.

Comment: Should I pick just one key to be my index? The one that I use the most for searches?

Comment: No, why? Index all queries that require performance. But don't index everything, indexes have their cost (disk/RAM usage, write performance hit). Measure, calculate and decide.

Comment: One point I would add is the cost of creating indexes is slower record insertions and additional memory and disk space consumed. In general you do want indexes for your common use cases to make them efficient but need to balance this against the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gain more efficient searches on the fields you choose at the cost of additional memory and disk space consumed.